# DHCP messages when connecting to home WI-Fi

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I inspected DHCP packets with wireshark. Expected result was to see 4 packets, namely DHCP discover, DHCP offer, DHCP request and DHCP ACK. I only see 3 as indicated by the picture. DHCP discover and DHCP request from my computer and DHCP ACK originated from the router. Where is DHCP offer? It should be between the first 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Discover? Your screenshot only shows a Request, a retransmission of the same Request, and an Ack. No Discover or Offer.

This is exactly what a lease renewal looks like: It skips the Discover and Offer if it's just renewing a previous successful lease.

Comment: How can I make it forget of the previous state? I would like to see all 4 of them.

Comment: That depends on your DHCP client implementation. Check the documentation.